# Symfony 3 - Firewall exlude one host

Tags: symfony, symfony-security

On one of my firewalls I would like to exlude one specific host. I tried many regex without success.

Bellow my example:

```
api:
        host: ^(?!.*(app\.domain\.com))
        pattern: .*
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use access control on security.yml like below:

```
    access_control:
    - { path: ^/$, roles:IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
    - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```